Do Ontario municipal property taxes only apply to surface rights?
It's my understanding there can be different kinds of rights associated with a given parcel of land in Ontario, Canada:

Surface Rights (most common)
Mining Rights
Timber rights
Other, such as fishing, railway, hydroelectric dam, waterway navigation, etc.

Question:
Are only the surface rights taxed by municipalities in Ontario via property taxes? Or are other kinds of rights taxed, too?
For example, it's possible for one person to own the surface rights of a property (via a PIN/parcel register), and a different person could own the mining rights to that same property (separate PIN/parcel register). I assume the surface rights PIN would be taxed by the municipality. But would the mining rights PIN also be taxed?

Good question. I have no idea what the answer is and don't have a good way to find out, but other lawyers with better access to Canadian law information also post answers here.
